# Is there a word that has the following meaning: to distribute a portion of funds

Tags: meaning

I am interested in a single word, if such a word exists.

Comment: Roget! Roget! Roget!

Comment: Hi idefine. Welcome to EL&U. Have you read [how to ask?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) It's a very interesting read on what makes a good question.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I haven't see that. I'll definitely check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Allocation**

Dictionary meaning is:

> An amount or portion of a resource assigned to a particular recipient.

You can also use **[Appropriation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appropriation)**, which means

> something that has been appropriated; specifically : money set aside by formal action for a specific use

Answer (score 1):

Incognito has a couple of good ones.  I would add **disbursement**.

Answer (score 0):

**Disburse** may meet your needs...

> verb (used with object), -bursed, -burs·ing.
>   1.
>   to pay out (money), especially for expenses; expend.
>   2.
>   to distribute or scatter: